# Using Windsor containers on web farms

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor

I'm developing a web application using ASP.NET MVC and I'm using Windsor Castle as an IoC container (both `WindsorControllerFactory` and for my internal components). Currently I'm creating and storing the container into the `Application` (`HttpApplicationState`) like this:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ...
        IWindsorContainer windsorContainer = new WindsorContainer();
        Application["WindsorContainer"] = windsorContainer;
        ...
    }

    protected void Application_End()
    {
        IWindsorContainer container = (IWindsorContainer)Application["WindsorContainer"];
        container.Dispose();

        Application["WindsorContainer"] = null;
    }
```

Is this a proper approach for applications which will run on Web farms? Are there any issues I need to be aware of? Is there a better place to put the container?

I know the `Application` state isn't shared across servers in a web farm, but I suppose this shouldn't be a problem as long as the data stored in the `Application` state isn't request-specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer to store the container in a [static gateway](http://blog.jpboodhoo.com/TheStaticGatewayPattern.aspx) like Ayende's [IoC from Rhino Commons](https://rhino-tools.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/rhino-tools/trunk/commons/Rhino.Commons/RhinoContainer/IoC.cs)

Comment: Cross-cutting concerns can be resolved more elegantly than by coupling the code with static references, but anyway - this doesn't really have much to do with what I asked. Even if you do use a static gateway, it won't be preserved across requests.

Comment: This was an answer to your question "Is there a better place to put the container?". Anyway, the container is usually not exposed to the rest of the application, so it doesn't make much of a difference. And using a static IoC *does* preserve it across requests, since it's internally stored in a static variable...